# Getting data by value

Tags: java, xpath

I'm messing around with XPath in Java and I seem to hit a wall. I've got the following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database>

    <student>
        <index>1234</index>
        <courselist>
            <course name="analiza matematyczna 1" grade="5.0"/>
            <course name="kurs programowania" grade="5.5"/>
            <course name="logika i struktury formalne" grade="4.0"/>
        </courselist>
    </student>

    <student>
        <index>5678</index>
        <courselist>
            <course name="logika i struktury formalne" grade="5.0"/>
            <course name="algebra z geometrią analityczną" grade="5.0"/>
            <course name="kurs programowania" grade="5.5"/>
        </courselist>
    </student>

</database>
```

and I want to retrieve all the index number that have at least one 4.0 grade. I can do those task separately but not altogether. I tried

```
/database/student/courselist/course[@grade='4.0']/@name | /database/student/index/text()
```

but the result is quite far from desired

```
[#text: 1234]    #good
name="logika i struktury formalne"    #even better, I can display where 4.0 was achieved
[#text: 5678]    #bad, this student doesn't have even one 4.0
```

My question is if such a query is even possible in XPath? Of course I would be extremely grateful for a working example :)

Comment: ///course[@grade="4.0"]/@name try this it is giving me corect result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current implementation gives `5678` as well, because the `|` operator in XPath means "and": it selects both the result of the left hand side *and* the result of the right hand side.

What you want is something like this:

```
/database/student[courselist/course[@grade='4.0']]/index/text()
```

Which reads as "give me all student elements having a courselist with a course with `grade=4.0`, and then give me the text contents of their `index` element.